# Статический IP и прокси

Tags: static-ip, proxy, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток. Есть ситуация: - виндовая корпоративная сеть, скорее всего ActiveDirector - ПК с Ubuntu11.04   и Win7 на борту дин.IP, значение которого "прыгает" в зависимости от расположения Марса  - win7 настроена windows-админом таким образом, что в ней у меня static ip (10.10.1.17)   windows-админ сети - windows-админ сети. Я не могу потребовать от него настройки Ubuntu :) Но могу узнать, какие-нибудь нюансы сетиЗадача: - Добиться того, чтобы этот же static ip был и в Ubuntu, причём без побочных эффектов.Вот такой вот конфиг у меня работает для dhcp:    auto lo    iface lo inet loopback    # dns    allow-hotplug eth0    iface eth0 inet dhcp    auto eth0С ним всё работает (за исключением почты :( ), но IP "прыгает". А вот такой вот конфиг я склепал, для получения static ip:    auto lo    iface lo inet loopback    iface eth0 inet static     address 10.10.1.17     netmask 255.255.255.0     gateway 10.10.1.2     auto eth0С ним я действительно имею, указанный мною, static ip, но не работают ftp, mail, даже ping в консоли =( Только http в браузере :)Ещё 1 нюанс заключается в том, что интернет доступен через proxy (но некоторые вещи, например ftp, доступны только напрямую). Пробовал шаманить с "система" > "параметры" > "сетевая proxy-служба", но безуспешно.Вот скриншот того, как это настроено в винде: ![снимок][1]Вопрос, что мне подправить в конфиге, для того, чтобы избавиться от этой проблемы, сохранив static ip? Желательно подоступнее, я newbie в *nix системах.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqF6Z.png

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, на удивление, помогли на [лоре](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/7035377):

> Надо исправить gateway на 10.10.1.3 и добавить строчку
>
> dns-nameservers 10.10.1.2